Can't unlock session (ubuntu 24.04)
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, whenever the session autolocks itself. I can't unlock it because there is no login box.


press ctrl+alt+f3 keys for tty. Then from cmd prompt run "sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target"
